# Transaction blocks not allowed in statement pooling mode

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, connection-pooling, hikaricp

I'm trying to persist (via spring-data-jpa and spring boot) an JPA entity which have reference to others entities and everything is fine locally but I got the below stack trace error when I deploy my app

```
2023-07-02T09:51:20.743Z  WARN 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection   : HikariPool-1 - Connection org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@73386d72 marked as broken because of SQLSTATE(08P01), ErrorCode(0)

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: transaction blocks not allowed in statement pooling mode
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2713) ~[postgresql-42.6.0.jar!/:42.6.0]
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2401) ~[postgresql-42.6.0.jar!/:42.6.0]
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:368) ~[postgresql-42.6.0.jar!/:42.6.0]
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:498) ~[postgresql-42.6.0.jar!/:42.6.0]
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:415) ~[postgresql-42.6.0.jar!/:42.6.0]
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:190) ~[postgresql-42.6.0.jar!/:42.6.0]
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeQuery(PgPreparedStatement.java:134) ~[postgresql-42.6.0.jar!/:42.6.0]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:52) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar!/:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar!/:na]
        at org.hibernate.sql.results.jdbc.internal.DeferredResultSetAccess.executeQuery(DeferredResultSetAccess.java:239) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.jar!/:6.2.2.Final]
        at org.hibernate.sql.results.jdbc.internal.DeferredResultSetAccess.getResultSet(DeferredResultSetAccess.java:163) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.jar!/:6.2.2.Final]
        at org.hibernate.sql.results.jdbc.internal.JdbcValuesResultSetImpl.advanceNext(JdbcValuesResultSetImpl.java:204) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.jar!/:6.2.2.Final]
        at org.hibernate.sql.results.jdbc.internal.JdbcValuesResultSetImpl.processNext(JdbcValuesResultSetImpl.java:84) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.jar!/:6.2.2.Final]
        at org.hibernate.sql.results.jdbc.internal.AbstractJdbcValues.next(AbstractJdbcValues.java:29) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.jar!/:6.2.2.Final]


2023-07-02T09:51:20.753Z  WARN 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 08P01
2023-07-02T09:51:20.753Z ERROR 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : FATAL: transaction blocks not allowed in statement pooling mode
2023-07-02T09:51:20.753Z  WARN 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 08006
2023-07-02T09:51:20.753Z ERROR 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : An I/O error occurred while sending to the backend.
2023-07-02T09:51:20.770Z ERROR 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.t.i.TransactionInterceptor           : Application exception overridden by rollback exception

org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: JDBC exception executing SQL [select p1_0.url,p1_0.api_key,c1_0.code from insurance_management.partner_region p1_0 join insurance_management.partner p2_0 on p1_0.partner_id=p2_0.id and lower(p2_0.name)=lower(?) join insurance_management.region r1_0 on p1_0.region_id=r1_0.id join insurance_management.country c1_0 on c1_0.id=r1_0.country_id and lower(c1_0.name)=lower(?) where p1_0.environment=? and lower(p1_0.url_type)=lower(?)] [FATAL: transaction blocks not allowed in statement pooling mode] [n/a]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:253) ~[spring-orm-6.0.9.jar!/:6.0.9]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:229) ~[spring-orm-6.0.9.jar!/:6.0.9]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:550) ~[spring-orm-6.0.9.jar!/:6.0.9]
        at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61) ~[spring-tx-6.0.9.jar!/:6.0.9]
        at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242) ~[spring-tx-6.0.9.jar!/:6.0.9]
        at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:152) ~[spring-tx-6.0.9.jar!/:6.0.9]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.9.jar!/:6.0.9]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:134) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.1.0.jar!/:3.1.0]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.9.jar!/:6.0.9]
        at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97) ~[spring-aop-6.0.9.jar!/:6.0.9]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.9.jar!/:6.0.9]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:223) ~[spring-aop-6.0.9.jar!/:6.0.9]
        at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy137.findPartnerConnectionInfos(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at fr.decathlon.services.QuoteService.createQuote(QuoteService.java:70) ~[classes!/:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343) ~[spring-aop-6.0.9.jar!/:6.0.9]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:196) ~[spring-aop-6.0.9.jar!/:6.0.9]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-6.0.9.jar!/:6.0.9]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:750) ~[spring-aop-6.0.9.jar!/:6.0.9]
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123) ~[spring-tx-6.0.9.jar!/:6.0.9]
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:391) ~[spring-tx-6.0.9.jar!/:6.0.9]
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-tx-6.0.9.jar!/:6.0.9]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.9.jar!/:6.0.9]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:750) ~[spring-aop-6.0.9.jar!/:6.0.9]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:702) ~[spring-aop-6.0.9.jar!/:6.0.9]
        at fr.decathlon.services.QuoteService$$SpringCGLIB$$0.createQuote(<generated>) ~[classes!/:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
        at fr.decathlon.controllers.InsuranceSubscriptionController.createQuote(InsuranceSubscriptionController.java:27) ~[classes!/:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343) ~[spring-aop-6.0.9.jar!/:6.0.9]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:196) ~[spring-aop-6.0.9.jar!/:6.0.9]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-6.0.9.jar!/:6.0.9]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:750) ~[spring-aop-6.0.9.jar!/:6.0.9]
        at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.MethodValidationInterceptor.invoke(MethodValidationInterceptor.java:141) ~[spring-context-6.0.9.jar!/:6.0.9]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.9.jar!/:6.0.9]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:750) ~[spring-aop-6.0.9.jar!/:6.0.9]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:702) ~[spring-aop-6.0.9.jar!/:6.0.9]
        at fr.decathlon.controllers.InsuranceSubscriptionController$$SpringCGLIB$$0.createQuote(<generated>) ~[classes!/:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:207) ~[spring-web-6.0.9.jar!/:6.0.9]


Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: JDBC exception executing SQL [select p1_0.url,p1_0.api_key,c1_0.code from insurance_management.partner_region p1_0 join insurance_management.partner p2_0 on p1_0.partner_id=p2_0.id and lower(p2_0.name)=lower(?) join insurance_management.region r1_0 on p1_0.region_id=r1_0.id join insurance_management.country c1_0 on c1_0.id=r1_0.country_id and lower(c1_0.name)=lower(?) where p1_0.environment=? and lower(p1_0.url_type)=lower(?)] [FATAL: transaction blocks not allowed in statement pooling mode] [n/a]
        at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:98) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.jar!/:6.2.2.Final]
        at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:56) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.jar!/:6.2.2.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:108) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.jar!/:6.2.2.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:94) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.jar!/:6.2.2.Final]
        at org.hibernate.sql.results.jdbc.internal.DeferredResultSetAccess.executeQuery(DeferredResultSetAccess.java:257) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.jar!/:6.2.2.Final]
        at org.hibernate.sql.results.jdbc.internal.DeferredResultSetAccess.getResultSet(DeferredResultSetAccess.java:163) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.jar!/:6.2.2.Final]
        at org.hibernate.sql.results.jdbc.internal.JdbcValuesResultSetImpl.advanceNext(JdbcValuesResultSetImpl.java:204) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.jar!/:6.2.2.Final]
        at org.hibernate.sql.results.jdbc.internal.JdbcValuesResultSetImpl.processNext(JdbcValuesResultSetImpl.java:84) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.jar!/:6.2.2.Final]
        at org.hibernate.sql.results.jdbc.internal.AbstractJdbcValues.next(AbstractJdbcValues.java:29) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.jar!/:6.2.2.Final]
        at org.hibernate.sql.results.internal.RowProcessingStateStandardImpl.next(RowProcessingStateStandardImpl.java:65) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.jar!/:6.2.2.Final]
        at org.hibernate.sql.results.spi.ListResultsConsumer.consume(ListResultsConsumer.java:198) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.jar!/:6.2.2.Final]
        at org.hibernate.sql.results.spi.ListResultsConsumer.consume(ListResultsConsumer.java:33) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.jar!/:6.2.2.Final]
        at org.hibernate.sql.exec.internal.JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.doExecuteQuery(JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.java:362) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.jar!/:6.2.2.Final]
        at org.hibernate.sql.exec.internal.JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.executeQuery(JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.java:168) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.jar!/:6.2.2.Final]
        at org.hibernate.sql.exec.internal.JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.list(JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.java:93) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.jar!/:6.2.2.Final]
        at org.hibernate.sql.exec.spi.JdbcSelectExecutor.list(JdbcSelectExecutor.java:31) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.jar!/:6.2.2.Final]
        at org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.lambda$new$0(ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.java:109) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.jar!/:6.2.2.Final]
        at org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.withCacheableSqmInterpretation(ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.java:302) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.jar!/:6.2.2.Final]
        at org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.performList(ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.java:243) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.jar!/:6.2.2.Final]
        at org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.QuerySqmImpl.doList(QuerySqmImpl.java:518) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.jar!/:6.2.2.Final]
        at org.hibernate.query.spi.AbstractSelectionQuery.list(AbstractSelectionQuery.java:367) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.jar!/:6.2.2.Final]
        at org.hibernate.query.spi.AbstractSelectionQuery.getSingleResult(AbstractSelectionQuery.java:473) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.jar!/:6.2.2.Final]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$SingleEntityExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:223) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.1.0.jar!/:3.1.0]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:92) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.1.0.jar!/:3.1.0]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:148) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.1.0.jar!/:3.1.0]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:136) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.1.0.jar!/:3.1.0]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:136) ~[spring-data-commons-3.1.0.jar!/:3.1.0]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:120) ~[spring-data-commons-3.1.0.jar!/:3.1.0]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:164) ~[spring-data-commons-3.1.0.jar!/:3.1.0]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:143) ~[spring-data-commons-3.1.0.jar!/:3.1.0]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.9.jar!/:6.0.9]
        at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:77) ~[spring-data-commons-3.1.0.jar!/:3.1.0]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.9.jar!/:6.0.9]
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123) ~[spring-tx-6.0.9.jar!/:6.0.9]
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:391) ~[spring-tx-6.0.9.jar!/:6.0.9]
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-tx-6.0.9.jar!/:6.0.9]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.9.jar!/:6.0.9]
        at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137) ~[spring-tx-6.0.9.jar!/:6.0.9]
        ... 126 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: transaction blocks not allowed in statement pooling mode
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2713) ~[postgresql-42.6.0.jar!/:42.6.0]
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2401) ~[postgresql-42.6.0.jar!/:42.6.0]
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:368) ~[postgresql-42.6.0.jar!/:42.6.0]
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:498) ~[postgresql-42.6.0.jar!/:42.6.0]
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:415) ~[postgresql-42.6.0.jar!/:42.6.0]
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:190) ~[postgresql-42.6.0.jar!/:42.6.0]
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeQuery(PgPreparedStatement.java:134) ~[postgresql-42.6.0.jar!/:42.6.0]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:52) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar!/:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar!/:na]
        at org.hibernate.sql.results.jdbc.internal.DeferredResultSetAccess.executeQuery(DeferredResultSetAccess.java:239) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.jar!/:6.2.2.Final]
        ... 159 common frames omitted

2023-07-02T09:51:20.779Z ERROR 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not roll back JPA transaction] with root cause

java.sql.SQLException: Connection is closed
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection$ClosedConnection.lambda$getClosedConnection$0(ProxyConnection.java:502) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar!/:na]
        at jdk.proxy3/jdk.proxy3.$Proxy84.rollback(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection.rollback(ProxyConnection.java:385) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar!/:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyConnection.rollback(HikariProxyConnection.java) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar!/:na]
        at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.AbstractLogicalConnectionImplementor.rollback(AbstractLogicalConnectionImplementor.java:121) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.jar!/:6.2.2.Final]
        at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.rollback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:290) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.jar!/:6.2.2.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.rollback(TransactionImpl.java:142) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.jar!/:6.2.2.Final]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doRollback(JpaTransactionManager.java:588) ~[spring-orm-6.0.9.jar!/:6.0.9]
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processRollback(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:835) ~[spring-tx-6.0.9.jar!/:6.0.9]
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.rollback(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:809) ~[spring-tx-6.0.9.jar!/:6.0.9]
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.completeTransactionAfterThrowing(TransactionAspectSupport.java:678) ~[spring-tx-6.0.9.jar!/:6.0.9]
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:395) ~[spring-tx-6.0.9.jar!/:6.0.9]
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-tx-6.0.9.jar!/:6.0.9]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.9.jar!/:6.0.9]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:750) ~[spring-aop-6.0.9.jar!/:6.0.9]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:702) ~[spring-aop-6.0.9.jar!/:6.0.9]
        at fr.decathlon.services.QuoteService$$SpringCGLIB$$0.createQuote(<generated>) ~[classes!/:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
        at fr.decathlon.controllers.InsuranceSubscriptionController.createQuote(InsuranceSubscriptionController.java:27) ~[classes!/:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
```

Here is the complete service

```
@Transactional
public QuoteResponse createQuote(QuoteRequest quoteRequest) {

    String deviceEpc = quoteRequest.getEpc();

    String partnerName = quoteRequest.getPartner();
    String countryName = quoteRequest.getCountry().getName();
    String operationType = CREATE_QUOTE.name().toLowerCase();

    PartnerConnectionInfos partnerConnectionInfos = quoteRepository.findPartnerConnectionInfos(partnerName, countryName, partnerEnvironment, operationType)
            .orElseThrow(() -> new PartnerInCountryException(""));

    String packageId = partnerCountryRepository.findPackageIdByPartnerAndCountry(partnerName, countryName)
            .orElseThrow(() -> new QuoteTemplateException(""))
            .trim();
    var createQuotePayload = BodyInserters.fromValue(LakaQuoteRequest.builder()
            .email(quoteRequest.getEmail())
            .packageId(packageId)
            .build());

    String requestUrl = partnerConnectionInfos.getUrl().trim();
    String countryCode = partnerConnectionInfos.getCountryCode().toLowerCase();

    String createQuoteResponse = WebClient.builder()
            .baseUrl(requestUrl)
            .build()
            .post()
            .body(createQuotePayload)
            .exchangeToMono(response -> response.bodyToMono(String.class)).block();

    Map<String, Object> createQuoteResponseToMap;
    try {
        createQuoteResponseToMap = new JSONParser(createQuoteResponse).parseObject();
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("");
    }

    String quoteId = (String) createQuoteResponseToMap.get("id");

    PartnerEntity partnerEntity = partnerRepository.findByNameIgnoreCase(partnerName)
            .orElseThrow(() -> new PartnerNotFoundException(""));

    DeviceEntity deviceEntity = deviceRepository.findByEpc(deviceEpc)
            .orElse(DeviceEntity.builder()
                    .epc(deviceEpc)
                    .build());

    UUID userUid = quoteRequest.getUid();
    UserEntity userEntity = userRepository.findByUid(userUid)
            .orElse(UserEntity.builder()
                    .uid(userUid)
                    .build());

    QuoteEntity quoteEntity = QuoteEntity.builder()
            .quoteId(quoteId)
            .user(userEntity)
            .device(deviceEntity)
            .partner(partnerEntity)
            .build();

    quoteRepository.save(quoteEntity);

    return QuoteResponse.builder()
            .url(requestUrl + "/" + quoteId)
            .callBackUrlSuccess(CallBackUrl.SUCCESS.getValue())
            .callBackUrlError(CallBackUrl.ERROR.getValue())
            .build();
}
```

Here is my datasource and jpa configuration in application.yaml file

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: ${DB_URL}
    username: ${DB_USER_NAME}
    password: ${DB_USER_PASSWORD}
  jpa:
    properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
        default_schema: my_schema
```

I use the default spring boot pool connection (Hikari).

My stack version :

1. JAVA : 17
2. Spring boot : 3.1.0
3. Spring data jpa : 3.1.0
4. Postgresql : 42.6.0

Someone have idea about how solve this problem ?

Thanks

Comment: Seems self explanatory.  Either don't use statement pooling in your connection pooler, or don't use transaction blocks.

Comment: @jjanes Yes, it seem explanatory but what do you call  transaction blocks ? I want to save user, device and quote simultaneously and rollback all in error case. So, I think transaction is a good practice to do that.

The idea that I have is to change the pool connection mode from "statement" to "transaction" for example but I don't found a way to do that for Hikari pool connection.

I found this (it's in french) https://public.dalibo.com/exports/formation/manuels/modules/w6/w6.handout.html but it's done in postgresql side, I think I need to do same on the Hikari pool connection

Answer (score 0):

The error you are observing is coming from PgBouncer, not PostgreSQL, and the root cause is particular PgBouncer instance is configured to use statement-level pooling, [which does not support multi-statement transactions](https://www.pgbouncer.org/features.html):

> **Statement pooling**
> Most aggressive method. This is transaction pooling with a twist: *Multi-statement transactions are disallowed*. This is meant to enforce “autocommit” mode on the client, mostly targeted at PL/Proxy.

The options are:

1. do not use PgBouncer at all or switch to session-level pooling
2. switch to transaction-level pooling, in that case you extra setup is required:

```
ignore_startup_parameters=extra_float_digits
server_reset_query_always=1
```

on PgBouncer side and `prepareThreshold=0` parameter in JDBC url